# Execute Google Bigquery projected queries using the API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

For cleaning up staging data in Google Bigquery I'm now using a class holding all the individual queries and a script to execute these queries as a job using the Bigquery API. I would prefer to manage these queries in Bigquery by saving them in the Project Queries section.

Is it possible to execute a query that is saved in the Project Queries section using the Bigquery API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've not found a way to get a handle on the project queries.  If you can structure the queries as views, then you can use Google Script to trigger a view read and subsequent table insert/append job.

With a little imagination, you can get achieve quite a lot with script and make it perform the common tasks similar to SSIS such as success / error logging, partition replacement and parallel job execution